# Integrated card reader doesn't work in linux mint, but it does in windows 10, any help?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sd-card

I spend like 4 hours looking for help and trying different things but anything works.
I installed Linux Mint alongside windows 10 today and it doesn't read any sd card, but Windows does, so, my question is, what could i do to make it works? I tried looking for the driver but it doesn't appear anywhere

Comment: Just to double check first things I would try is in the terminal type `lsblk` then insert the card and type `lsblk` again if there is any difference the card are being read but not mounted lets try this first.

Comment: If you tried several things, you are likely to get answers or suggestions to try the same things. That is a waste of time for everybody. I don't know how the card reader is connected, but you should start with commands like `lspci` for listing PCI bus slots, and `lsusb` for listing USB devices. Can you add the things you tried to your question? It may also help if you revealed the brand of your PC and, if you have it, the card reader. You might get such information in Windows or from the commands I suggested.

Comment: Do you have firmware for the reader installed? Maybe some part of firmware directory is not installed by default on Mint.

Answer (score -1):

If you get the message 'Not Authorized to perform operation', and you have the Chrome Remote Desktop.

The solution is stop the Chrome Remote Desktop Service:

/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --stop

Start again the Chrome remote desktop service:

/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start